# SQLIte MAX vs Postgresql GREATEST, with strings

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql, sqlite, max

According to some other posts, in SQLite max() function is equivalent of Postgresql GREATEST() function.
Can someone explain strange behavior of SQlite max function with strings:

```
    select max ('rb','VISA', 'Visa', 'Visa Card1', 'VISA VISA Card', 'Visaaa')
```

returns 'rb'. Why?!? 
I would expect 'VISA VISA Card' as longest string to be returned as result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the length of a string is irrelevant.  It's looking at the highest value according to collating sequence.

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc

Secondly, the default collating sequence is BINARY and so it's looking at the ASCII values.

- https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation_sequence_examples
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
- In the ASCII table, `r` has a value of 162, and `V` has a value of 126, so `r` is higher...
- You can force NOCASE :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f5d34/2

Thirdly, it is not relevant that you're using `MAX()` as an aggregating or scalar function, however you use it gives the same result.

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6fbe6/1

Finally, the implication that PostgreSQL gives the longest string when using GREATEST() is wrong too...

- It just has a different collation sequence (which order the characters are valued) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6fbe6/4

Comment: Ok, is there another way to retreive the longest string?

Comment: From a ***table*** you can jump through a few hoops...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/33d57/8  *(Add `WHERE rank=0` to get the longest strings, or `WHERE length_rank=0 AND string_rank=0` to get just one string...)*

Answer (score 2):

It's returning the highest value according to the character representation as bytes (lower-case higher values than upper-case).

Change to `select max ('rb','vISA', 'Visa', 'Visa Card1', 'VISA VISA Card', 'Visaaa')` and the result is **vISA**.

#### Re Comment

> And is there any way to retrieve the longest string?

If you wanted the longest string and assuming that the data is in a column (named **mystring** in this case) of a table (named **test** in this case) then you could use :-

```
SELECT mystring FROM test ORDER BY length(mystring) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

e.g.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (mystring TEXT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('rb'),('VISA'),('Visa Card1'),('VISA VISA Card'),('Visaaa');
SELECT mystring FROM test ORDER BY length(mystring) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Results in :-

[image]

- Note, the result would be arbitrary (from the longest string) should there be multiple strings with the same longest length.

Comment: And is there any way to retrieve the longest string?